# Putting a new value into a register with lui (load upper immediate) and ori (OR immediate) [MIPS]

Tags: assembly, mips, 32-bit

[MIPS]

Assume there is the stored value 0x12345678 in `$s0`.

Let's assume I want to put now another value into `$s0` (say for example 0x87654321), then I have to put the value in two steps (at least I have learned it this way) with the `lui` operation and the `ori`.

```
lui $s0, 0x8765
ori $s0, $s0, 0x4321
```

I know this works if `$s0` is `0` at the beginning, but I'm actually not sure if the `lui` operation sets the second half to 0's or if it just replaces the first half with my new input 0x8765.

So, my question is:

 Does it work even if there's a stored value in `$s0` or do I have to set the value of `$s0` to `0` and then set the upper half and lower half ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should always consult an instruction set reference about such issues. Or you could even just try it.

But to answer your question, yes, `lui` clears the low bits.